# Altering the default boot option on CentOS

Tags: centos, boot, windows, options

I recently installed a copy of CentOS onto my main hard drive (I now have Windows 7 and CentOS). Whilst installing CentOS, I accidentally set it to be the main boot option, so when I start my PC I have three seconds to select Windows 7 or it automatically boots into CentOS. I would rather Windows 7 be the default option -- how can I change it?

Comment: Can you paste the output of `cat /boot/grub/menu.lst`, I can alter the settings so that Windows can be default boot option for you.

Answer (score 2):

CentOS uses [GRUB](http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/) for its bootloader. There's a page in the CentOS install guide that covers [modifying GRUB's configuration](http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Installation_Guide-en-US/s1-grub-configfile.html). First, you need to open `/boot/grub/grub.conf` in a text editor, but the text editor needs to be running as root so you'll have permission to edit the file. One way is to run this in a terminal:

```
$ sudo gedit /boot/grub/grub.conf
```

Once you have the file open, look for `default` near the beginning. The options are 0-indexed, so if it says `default 0` it means it'll default to the first option in the list. Change it to e.g. `default 1` if Windows 7 is the second option

Comment: ok, I thought its menu.lst. Nevertheless, +1 for the link @MichaelMrozek :-)

Comment: @Nikhil Usually `menu.lst` is a symlink for `grub.conf` (so either would work)